# How to ssh into rancher desktop node?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, k3s, rancher-desktop

I just started to use Rancher and request to correct me for any wrong terminology.

Earlier I was using minikube on Macbook which provide SSH easily using `minikube ssh` for troubleshooting. As I am newbie to Rancher Desktop and wanted to do SSH on Rancher Desktop node similar to minikube.

I googled for same but unfortunately I didn't get any fruitful answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On recent versions (1.3 on) you can use the `rdctl` utility, which ships with Rancher Desktop, and run `rdctl shell COMMAND` or `rdctl shell` to ssh into the VM.

Comment: finally, nice and clean command.

Answer (score 4):

You can access using below(first line):

$***LIMA_HOME="$HOME/Library/Application Support/rancher-desktop/lima" "/Applications/Rancher Desktop.app/Contents/Resources/resources/darwin/lima/bin/limactl" shell 0***

lima-rancher-desktop:/Users/kulsharm2$ uname -a
Linux lima-rancher-desktop 5.10.103-0-virt #1-Alpine SMP Tue, 08 Mar 2022 10:06:11 +0000 x86_64 Linux

Answer (score 3):

you should be able to use `limactl show-ssh NAME` where `NAME` is the name of your rancher node (which you can list using `limactl list`).

alternatively, you can also use `ps -ef | grep rancher` which will list the rancher processes, some of which containing ssh information:

```bash
126693404  2136  1983   0 Thu12PM ??         0:00.01 ssh -F /dev/null -o IdentityFile="/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Application Support/rancher-desktop/lima/_config/user" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost=yes -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o Compression=no -o BatchMode=yes -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o Ciphers="^aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com" -o User=xxxxxx -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath="/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Application Support/rancher-desktop/lima/0/ssh.sock" -o ControlPersist=5m -p 49314 127.0.0.1 -- sshfs :/tmp/rancher-desktop /tmp/rancher-desktop -o slave -o allow_other
```

you can then manually ssh by using the same port and identity file as the command is using.
In this case:

```bash
 ssh -p 49314 -i '/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Application Support/rancher-desktop/lima/_config/user' xxxxxx@localhost
```

This is, for sure, less convenient but seems to be working well.

Comment: `limactl list` doesn't appear to work as the config is located in a different directory as the other answer suggests.

Comment: Another option to use the default ssh key is to add the default public key to the file:  `/home/$USER.linux/.ssh/authorized_keys'` once inside the VM using `rdctl shell`.